# Python Complex List-Comprehensions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is it any way to write this for loops with List-Comprehensions

```
p_list = []
pt_list = []

for pt in part_task_list:
    pt.progress = pt.progress * pt.project_task.weight
    pt_list.append(pt)

for p in part_list:
    for pt in pt_list:
        if pt.part.id == p.id:
            p.final_progress += pt.progress
        p.finla_progress = p.final_progress/100
        p_list.append(p)
```

Comment: You have 2 loops which one you want to convert it into list comprehension

Comment: I don't think it's possible in your case. List comprehensions are designed to produce lists. Here you are doing attributes assignements inside your loop, which can't be done inside a list comprehension.

Comment: Won’t `pt_list` just be a copy of `part_task_list` (and `p_list` be many copies of it concatenated)?  Also, the typo `finla_progress` is an excellent lesson in the virtues of compound assignment.

Comment: Is the indentation of the two last lines correct? I mean; does the final `p_list` contain `len(part_list)*len(pt_list)` elements, or only `len(part_list)` elements? And: do you consume `part_task_list` and `part_list` during the process, or are the side-effects on those lists useful after the process?